# track click in a image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have an image with some areas like this

```
<img class="interactiveImage" src="images/demo.png" width="466" height="746" alt="" usemap="#area-img">
<map name="area-img">
<area shape="polygon" coords="112,650,110,683,147,685,148,651" id="area1"/>
<area shape="polygon" coords="208,647,208,685,247,687,247,649" id="area2"/>
<area shape="polygon" coords="312,649,310,684,349,684,349,648" id="area3"/>
```

I want (using jquery) to track the point of image where a user clicked and the id of area shape if that click is inside of an area shape.

I want point of image not point of document (independently if user has scrolled ).

i want not only have id of area which clicked but and position of image point (x,y) which clicked , or only position of image point (x,y) which clicked (if user do click out of areas)

Thanks !

Comment: Hi Diego, Can you show us what you have tried.

Comment: @Cymen i think you're right

Comment: but how track point position of click?

Comment: For real? Check the link

Comment: i want not only have id of area which clicked but and position of image point (x,y) which clicked , or only position of image point (x,y) which clicked (if user do click out of areas

Comment: @CKY any help for my problem?